# htaccess redirect - I need to redirect subfolder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect subfolder to subdomain using htaccess

For example:

redirect www.example.com/test (also http://, https://, http://www, https://www)
to
https://user.example.com

how do I do it?

also, how it should be if I need to redirect it to https://user.example.com/test

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/?$ https://user.example.com/test [R=301,L]
```

Don't forget to enable *mod_rewrite* if it's not yet done

Comment: Thanks. It works! how do we modify it if we need to also satisfy redirect  from example.com/test to https://user.example.com/test ?

Comment: What you're asking is what this code does. Did i misunderstood your question ?

Comment: it doesn't redirect if we input example.com/test to https://user.example.com/test
(that means it doesn't redirect if we don't have http, https, or www in front)

Comment: I think your problem comes from a misconfiguration of your domain. I guess `www.example.com` and `example.com` do not share the same document root folder (that's why your rule is not executed when you're under `example.com`)

Answer (score -1):

[Look at original answer at](https://serverfault.com/a/419482/101768)

Can you do a different  for blog.example.com?

If you can, just put your Redirect config there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.example.com
    Redirect / http://example.com/blog/
</VirtualHost>
```

If for some reason you still need to piggy-back on the other vhost, or need to handle all subdomains and not just "blog", then use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```